# Warning (Code 1264): Out of range value for column 'HireDate' at row 1 in sql

Tags: mysql, wampserver

insert into Employee values(2,"Brown","Barry",2011-08-12,1,11,null);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Warning (Code 1264): Out of range value for column 'HireDate' at row 1 what does this mean in sql guys???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning#1264:out of range error in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216642/warning1264out-of-range-error-in-mysql)

Comment: it means Your data is not valid for this column. Too long or different type.

Comment: Where is your query ?

Comment: sorry Emanuel i will edit

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, when entering a date into a query it must be wrapped in quotes as it is considered to be a text string.

```
insert into Employee 
    values(2,"Brown","Barry",'2011-08-12',1,11,null);
```