# Error: Out of range value for column mysql rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have sql table:

```
-- Table structure for rb_amazon_daily
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `rb_amazon_daily`;
CREATE TABLE `rb_amazon_daily` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `book_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `marketplace` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amazon_kdp_avg_list_price` decimal(12,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amazon_kdp_royalty_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amazon_kdp_revenue_in_usd` decimal(13,13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amazon_kdp_royalty_in_usd` decimal(13,13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amazon_kdp_paid_downloads` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amazon_kdp_free_downloads` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amazon_ku_pages_read` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amazon_ku_revenue_in_usd` decimal(12,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_space_revenue_in_usd` decimal(12,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_space_royalty_in_usd` decimal(12,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_space_paperbacks_sold` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `daily_total_revenue` decimal(12,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `daily_total_royalty` decimal(12,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=301 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

[image]
And I have

```
class AmazonDaily < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "rb_amazon_daily"
end
```

But then when I try to save somedata to database

```
#<AmazonDaily:0x007fffef743a00
 id: nil,
 date: Sat, 16 Jul 2016,
 book_title: "Catalyst Moon: Incursion",
 marketplace: "Amazon.com",
 amazon_kdp_avg_list_price: 0.299e1,
 amazon_kdp_royalty_type: "70%",
 amazon_kdp_revenue_in_usd: 0.598e1,
 amazon_kdp_royalty_in_usd: 0.408e1,
 amazon_kdp_paid_downloads: 2,
 amazon_kdp_free_downloads: 0,
 amazon_ku_pages_read: 0,
 amazon_ku_revenue_in_usd: 0.0,
 create_space_revenue_in_usd: 0.0,
 create_space_royalty_in_usd: 0.0,
 create_space_paperbacks_sold: 0,
 daily_total_revenue: 0.598e1,
 daily_total_royalty: 0.408e1>
```

I got an error:
Error: Out of range value for column
    `

> home/jonsdirewolf/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.9/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in
>   `_query': Mysql2::Error: Out of range value for column
>   'amazon_kdp_revenue_in_usd' at row 1: INSERT INTO`rb_amazon_daily
>   `(`date`,`book_title`,`marketplace`,`amazon_kdp_avg_list_price`,`
>   amazon_kdp_royalty_type`,`amazon_kdp_revenue_in_usd`,`
>   amazon_kdp_royalty_in_usd`,`amazon_kdp_paid_downloads`,`
>   amazon_kdp_free_downloads`,`amazon_ku_pages_read`,`
>   amazon_ku_revenue_in_usd`,`create_space_revenue_in_usd`,`
>   create_space_royalty_in_usd`,`create_space_paperbacks_sold`,`
>   daily_total_revenue`,`daily_total_royalty`) VALUES ('2016-07-16',
>   'Catalyst Moon: Incursion', 'Amazon.com', 2.99, '70%', 5.98, 4.08, 2,
>   0, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, 5.98, 4.08) (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)

`
What do I do?

Comment: Could it have something to do with 'date' being length 0?

Comment: @user7733611 no, definetely - I tried to set length of date but navicat set it to zero when I saved table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing was in my decimal definition in sql table, I needed to alter my decimal columns likefo example:

```
  `amazon_kdp_revenue_in_usd` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
```

> The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The
>   ranges of values for the arguments in MySQL 5.7 are as follows:
>
> M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1
>   to 65.
>
> D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the
>   scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

(this helped me: [Warning#1264:out of range error in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216642/warning1264out-of-range-error-in-mysql))