# ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'amount' at row 1

Tags: mysql

With this command:

```
mysql>  insert into irctc_cap ( lid,amount,type) VALUES (296,-1000,128);

ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'amount' at row 1
```

Mysql version:    Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19,

As per [Warning#1264:out of range error in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216642/warning1264out-of-range-error-in-mysql) I see that this problem should not come as amount has `length` of 12,4

[image: phpmyadmin snapshot of amount field]

Comment: You will get this error if amount is defined as UNSIGNED. What ide does the image come from?

Comment: @P.Salmon i've not used unsigned anywhere for this field

Comment: You appear to be using PhpMyAdmin. Scroll to the right and have a look at *Attributes*.

Comment: sorry using `desc` it shows as ` decimal(5,2)  `. I'll increase the size. Phpmyadmin showing 12,4 instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data type is `DECIMAL(5,2)`, this means five digits *total*, two of which are to the right of the decimal point. So the greatest value you can use is 999.99, and the least value is -999.99. Those are the most you can fit in five digits.

If you don't use strict mode, this generates a warning and truncates the value you tried to use to five digits:

```
mysql> insert into irctc_cap values (296,-1000,128);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.02 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                         |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'amount' at row 1 |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from irctc_cap;
+------+---------+------+
| lid  | amount  | type |
+------+---------+------+
|  296 | -999.99 |  128 |
+------+---------+------+
```

If you use strict mode, the warning becomes an error:

```
mysql> set sql_mode=strict_all_tables;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into irctc_cap values (296,-1000,128);
ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'amount' at row 1
```

I'm not sure why phpMyAdmin is showing the wrong data type.

Use `DESCRIBE` or `SHOW CREATE TABLE` or `SELECT column_type FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='irctc_cap' AND COLUMN_NAME='amount'` to get the accurate definition of the column.